# Installing .Net Framework 1.1 SP1 leads to error "WindowsUpdate_E0434F4D"

Tags: windows-vista, .net-1.1

When installing .Net Framework 1.1, the SP1 cannot be installed under Vista. Using Windows Update I get "WindowsUpdate_E0434F4D", doing it manually as administrator will result in "SLC542.tmp has stopped working".

This does not depend on whether I activated UAC or not.

I have no possibility to repair the framework 1.1, only to uninstall and reinstall, but the problem persists. (sorry, Razzie, but the link doesn't do it for me)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the information on this link?

[Windows Update Failed – Detailed Error Code “E0434F4D”](http://blogs.msdn.com/astebner/archive/2004/11/23/268934.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I personally ran into this problem because of preinstalled software on my HP notebook. Reinstalling Windows without it and then installing .net myself (and afterwards installing all the HP provided software) solved the problem.

Do not install the .Net Framework 1.1 with SP1 from the HP Tools DVD for Vista.